# Not able to echo to slots in BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I newly started working with BeagleBone Black and Device Tree Overlays.
I wrote a Device Tree Overlay, compiled it and *copied to /lib/firmware*, but when I am trying to echo it to */sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots* I get this error:

```
root@arm:~# echo APOLLO-PCB-RevA > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

When I *cat* the slots I find the following:

```
root@arm:~# cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
 0: PF----  -1 
 1: PF----  -1 
 2: PF----  -1 
 3: PF----  -1
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: The capemgr will spit out more useful messages in `/var/log/syslog`. This is where you're most likely to find your problem. If it isn't obvious, add the relevant logs to your question.

Comment: As a side note, if you wanted to add this to your uEnv.txt to load at boot, you need to update the initramfs boot image with `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Thanks @CJxD for the reply.
Actually I am trying to integrate ADAU1761 with BeagleBone Black. I making changes directly in the device tree to configure a sound card. is it possible?

Comment: When I checked the /var/log/syslog, I am getting : No soundcards found error messges. Sound cards are not getting configured.

Comment: It should be possible to do what you're doing, yes. Can you paste your syslog on pastebin.com? I'll take a quick look to see if there's anything I recognize. Perhaps your source file too.

Comment: Thanks @CJxD.
I have pasted the syslog file in pastebin.com with the name /var/log/syslog: 
http://pastebin.com/vY9vaaHk

Comment: The device tree code is : http://pastebin.com/XBs4E21C
Here I am changing directly in the device tree to create a adau1761 audio codec sound card

Comment: I am getting the following error from dmesg command:
[   11.597660] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: disagrees about version of symbol devm_regmap_init_i2c
[   11.597695] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: Unknown symbol devm_regmap_init_i2c (err -22)
[   11.597710] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: disagrees about version of symbol i2c_register_driver
[   11.597721] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: Unknown symbol i2c_register_driver (err -22)
[   11.597738] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: disagrees about version of symbol i2c_del_driver
[   11.597748] snd_soc_adau1761_i2c: Unknown symbol i2c_del_driver (err -22)

Comment: Okay, so I didn't see any errors in syslog (I'm guessing you forgot to load the firmware into slots, could you do this first and re-paste?) but I did notice that the firmware takes control of the HDMI pins. If you're going to let it do this, you should disable the BB-BONELT-HDMI and HDMIN firmwares from being loaded in your uEnv.txt. The other thing I noticed was that the firmware does not yet specify the i2c2 pinmux so it will rely on you having loaded BB-I2C2 (I'm presuming you're using kernel 4.x, otherwise it's BB-I2C1). I don't mind adding the pinmux in for you though.

Comment: Thank you @CJxD for the reply.
I have black listed the HDMI module.
And how to load the firmware into the slots?
I use 4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 version.

Comment: I disabled the HDMI in uEnv.txt file, made some more changes in the device tree. this is my new syslog file: http://pastebin.com/SWa1T7ZS 
My new device tree is: http://pastebin.com/qtLKqm3c
Please help me if I am going wrong

Comment: Oops, the capemgr reports to /var/log/messages after boot. Show me that log instead

Comment: I am not finding any file named messages. Do you mean dmesg? i have pasted dmesg log: http://pastebin.com/RabWApqC
Thank you @CJxD

Comment: I found this in the log: [   13.396742]  remoteproc1: Direct firmware load for am335x-pru1-fw failed with error -2
[   13.396776]  remoteproc1: failed to load am335x-pru1-fw
[   13.407044] pru-rproc 4a338000.pru1: booting the PRU core manually
remoteproc1: powering up 4a338000.pru1
remoteproc1: Direct firmware load for am335x-pru1-fw failed with error -2
remoteproc1: request_firmware failed: -2
pru-rproc 4a338000.pru1: rproc_boot failed
remoteproc1: releasing 4a338000.pru1
pru-rproc: probe of 4a338000.pru1 failed with error -2.
what does this mean?

Comment: Thank you @CJxD for the guidance! :). Finally I configured a sound card. **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ADAU1761 [ADI ADAU1761], device 0: Playback adau-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0. But when I am trying to play a audio.wav file.I am getting the following error. aplay: set_params:1297: Unable to install hw params. I programmed the hw params by refering to the example in : https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/sound/adau1361

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out! `dmesg` is only really for boot logging. There should be a `/var/log/messages` but maybe it's been moved in kernel 4.x. Anyway, could you write a concise answer for future readers?

Comment: Now trying to solve "Unable to install hw params" error. Once it is solved, sure will write a complete steps to configure an adau1761 sound card.